# basic_string.h errors on porting from with gcc 4.6.3 to 5.4.0

Tags: c++, string, g++

Re posted (although not easy to format when some of the g++ output lines seen to be several 100 chars long!).

I have a c++ program that compiles fine on an Ubuntu 12.04 using g++ version 4.6.3. I decided to use a more up to date O/S and g++ - but i'm getting a few strange compile errors.  Now I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and g++ 5.4.0. What is strange is the initial error message I get to .cpp source file does not point to a line of code that should generate that type of message.  The errors I see are:

```
 In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/string:52:0,
             from pkcs11_test.h:17,
             from pkcs11_attr.h:13,
             from pkcs11_attr.cpp:16:
 /usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h: In instantiation of ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits,
 _Alloc>::basic_string(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) 
 [with _CharT = unsigned char; _Traits = std::char_traits<unsigned char>; _Alloc = sec_allocator<unsigned char>]’:
 pkcs11_attr.cpp:48:9:   required from here
 /usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:399:62: error: no matching function for call to
 ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<unsigned char, std::char_traits<unsigned char>, sec_allocator<unsigned char>
  >::_Alloc_hider::_Alloc_hider(std::__cxx11::basic_string<unsigned char, std::char_traits<unsigned char>,
  sec_allocator<unsigned char> >::pointer, const allocator_type&)’
   : _M_dataplus(_M_local_data(), __str._M_get_allocator()) // TODO A traits


 /usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:108:2: note: candidate: std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits,
 _Alloc>::_Alloc_hider::_Alloc_hider(std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::pointer, const _Alloc&) [with
 _CharT = unsigned char; _Traits = std::char_traits<unsigned char>; _Alloc = sec_allocator<unsigned char>;
 std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::pointer = unsigned char*]
 _Alloc_hider(pointer __dat, const _Alloc& __a = _Alloc())


/usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:108:2: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 
‘const allocator_type {aka const std::allocator<unsigned char>}’ to ‘const sec_allocator<unsigned char>&’
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:106:14: note: candidate: std::__cxx11::basic_string<unsigned char,
 std::char_traits<unsigned char>, sec_allocator<unsigned char> >::_Alloc_hider::_Alloc_hider(const
 std::__cxx11::basic_string<unsigned char, std::char_traits<unsigned char>, sec_allocator<unsigned char>     >::_Alloc_hider&)
 struct _Alloc_hider : allocator_type // TODO check __is_final


/usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_string.h:106:14: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
makefile:16: recipe for target 'pkcs11_attr.o' failed

make: *** [pkcs11_attr.o] Error 1
```

The error message doesn't actually point to sensible line it points to the return statement - as per below.

The code is:

```
 byteString CkAttribute::asByteString () const {
     byteString retVal;

 if( pValue )
     copyCkBStringToBString( (unsigned char *)pValue, ulValueLen, retVal );
 // end if

  <<<<< error points to the below line>>>>
  return retVal;
}
```

The 12.04 Ubuntu is 32 bit and the new 16.04 Ubuntu is 64 bit.  But i have installed g++multilib and tried to compile it with -m32 on the new platform.  However, I get the exact same error.  The program I'm compiling is quite big and consists of over 12 .cpp source files - all of which compile just fine - it is just this one error in this one source file.  It is driving me mad!!

Comment: Please print the relevant part of your code.

Comment: But the point is that it does not point to any actual code in the pkcs11_attr.cpp source module.

Comment: With is the code . with g++ saying the error is on the return valuebyteString CkAttribute::asByteString () const {
 byteString retVal;

 if( pValue )
  copyCkBStringToBString( (unsigned char *)pValue, ulValueLen, retVal );
 // end if

 return retVal;
}

Comment: also I forgot that the orginal IDE is running on 32 bit - but the new IDE is 64 bit.  What is strange is its flagging up a number of //TODO comments in the basic_string.h header file.

Comment: Just to test it out - I commented out all the above code and g++ still complained about line 48 in the source module - which is now just a comment.  Very very strange